# JAXB post api does not accept json request with generic 500 error in java

Tags: java, api, post, jackson, jaxb

I have to accept and return json using post api :

my api looks like this:

```
@Path("path/v1")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class ServiceCommonImpl implements ServiceCommon {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServiceCommonImpl.class);
    private Authorizor authorizor;
    private Validator validator;
    private ServiceCommonBO ServiceCommonBO;
    private Map<String, String> envMap;

    @POST
     
    @Path("details")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })  
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getAcquirerIdCDetailsPOST(CRequestType Id,
            @QueryParam("Format") String format,
            @HeaderParam("clientid") String userId) {
    
        return getCDetails(Id,format, userId);      
    }
```

**This api accepts XML request but not json, when json is given then it throws generic 500 message with no details**

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Are you sure there is no detail in the log file?

Comment: which log file are you talking about, the tomcat one?

Comment: Yes, the Tomcat one.

Comment: it does not have any log related to this , is there a way to add these logs ?

Comment: You checked the `logs/catalina.out` file? You checked all the log files of Tomcat? If not there, then the webapp server you're using is by default set up to hide stacktraces, so you need to configure it to show the stacktrace on the 500 error page. How to do that depends on which webapp server you're using (TomEE, Glashfish, JBoss, ...).

Comment: i am using tomcat 8.5.5

Comment: Tomcat doesn't do the `@Path` annotation, which means you have some framework in there handling that, and the framework is likely suppressing the stacktrace.